# Use VSTS node api to query for all commits in a particular branch

Tags: node.js, git, typescript, azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api

I've been using the [vsts-node-api](https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-node-api) with some degree of success.

However what I want to do it to query for all the commits in a particular branch. This is described on the REST api documentation found [here](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/git/commits#in-the-history-of-a-branch).

However the node api only allows you to query for commits in a repository using this method of the GitApi

```
getCommits(repositoryId: string, searchCriteria: GitInterfaces.GitQueryCommitsCriteria, project?: string, skip?: number, top?: number): Promise<GitInterfaces.GitCommitRef[]>;
```

The `GitInterfaces.GitQueryCommitsCriteria` has this interface

```
export interface GitQueryCommitsCriteria {
    $skip: number;
    $top: number;
    author: string;
    compareVersion: GitVersionDescriptor;
    excludeDeletes: boolean;
    fromCommitId: string;
    fromDate: string;
    historyMode: GitHistoryMode;
    ids: string[];
    includeLinks: boolean;
    includeWorkItems: boolean;
    itemPath: string;
    itemVersion: GitVersionDescriptor;
    toCommitId: string;
    toDate: string;
    user: string;
}
```

As you can see the getCommits does not have a branch parameter and the Query interface doesn't either so I'm a bit stumped on how to do this.

To give some context, what I am trying to achieve is that when a PR is updated or created I want to check to the source branch of the pr contains the lastest commit of the target branch to confirm that the source branch is up to date with the target branch.

Comment: Looks like a bug in client generation. I have raised a bug for it internally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For now, get commits of a branch is not available for vsts-node-api. And you can also follow up the issue [Enable to get commits of a branch](https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-node-api/issues/149).

And there are two workarounds for now:

- Workaround 1: use REST call to get the commits of a branch.
- Workaround 2: clone/get the git repo locally, and then execute `git log branchname --oneline` to get the commits of the specified branch.

Answer (score 2):

Sorry this is old, but this seems to work for me:

```
var criteria = new GitQueryCommitsCriteria()
{
    HistoryMode = GitHistoryMode.FirstParent,
    ItemVersion = new GitVersionDescriptor
    {
        Version = m_branch.Name,
        VersionType = GitVersionType.Branch,
        VersionOptions = GitVersionOptions.FirstParent
    }
};
```